# Are there authoritative JSON schema definitions for SCIM 2.0 schemas?

Tags: scim, scim2

I've been unable to find authoritative schema definitions in JSON format for resources and messages defined in the SCIM 2.0 RFCs.

While the RFCs are pretty specific and a number of SCIM endpoint implementations do publish their JSON schemas (many slightly different or modified, sadly), it would be nice if there were a repository with an authoritative set for each of the standard URNs:

- `urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkResponse`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:ResourceType`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Schema`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:ServiceProviderConfig`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User`
- `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User`

Can anyone point me at such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any of the :api:message: schemas, no, there is no SCIM JSON example in any of the specification documents.Inside of RFC 7644, BulkRequest and BulkResponse are defined in section 3.7, Error in 3.12, PatchOp in 3.5.2(loosely), and SearchRequest in 3.4.3. All of these are defined in text and do not have clearly defined properties in the SCIM JSON schema.

RFC 7643 has JSON examples of ServiceProviderConfig, Schema, and ResourceType in 8.7.2, and of core user, core group, and enterprise user in 8.7.1. However, immediately preceding all of the examples in RFC 7643 is this text in section 8.7:

> The following is intended as an example of the SCIM schema
> representation in JSON format for SCIM resources.  Where permitted,
> individual values and schema MAY change.  This example includes
> schema representations for "User", "Group", and "EnterpriseUser";
> other schema representations are possible.

This opens the door to variance in the section 8.7.1/8.7.2 JSON schema examples. MAY is a tricky word in RFC terms, and many implementers try to stick as closely to the schema defined in 8.7.1/8.7.2 as possible. That quoted blurb weakens any attempt to label these as truly authoritative, however.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I would have expected that schemata associated with registered URNs would have authoritative definitions, rather than partial or missing examples, especially since the goal of the SCIM protocol is interoperability! I wanted to trust that a document referring to a registered URN actually had specific attributes, and it appears that's not possible. Nightmare for provisioning scenarios.

Comment: You're sort of in luck - while SCIM 2.0 was published in 2015, the SCIM Working Group within the IETF was rechartered about 2 years ago. It's moving slowly (lot of first time contributors!), but this is both something that probably fits into the new charter and isn't too complicated or controversial.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks again for the help. I’ve been involved in two major SCIM endpoint projects now and should probably see about getting involved.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely an answer to the question, but for anyone else searching for machine-readable schema definitions, there's an OpenAPI schema created by the Gluu Federation at https://github.com/GluuFederation/scim/blob/master/scim-server/src/main/resources/gluu-scim-openapi.yaml

It's not authoritative, and it includes some Gluu-specific extensions that you may want to remove, but it's a useful starting point.